# how to display a html page with image in android?

Tags: android

hi i want to display my html image on android emulator, please help

```
package com.Htmlview;

import ja va.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.MessageFormat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Htmlview extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);
        try {

               String imageString="<html><body>" +
                "<h2>Norwegian Mountain Trip</h2>" +
                "<img src=\"C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/pulpit.jpg\" alt=\"Pulpit rock\" width=\"304\" height=\"228\" /></body></html>";
                AssetManager mgr = this.getAssets(); 
                InputStream is = mgr.open("index3.html");
                BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(is); // read the contents of the file 

              webview.loadData(MessageFormat.format(imageString,arguments),"text/html", "UTF-8");

                   } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never going to be able to access something on your workstation's hard drive from within Android.  What you want to do is put the image into the `assets` folder in your Android app (which will then get bundled into the app) and link to it appropriately with `file:///android_assets/`.  There are other ways of dealing with the issue, but that is the simplest.

Comment: hi womble,its nt working please check my code                           String imageString="<html><body>" +
          "<h2>Norwegian Mountain Trip</h2>" +
          "<img src=\"file:///android_assets/pulpit.jpg\" alt=\"Pulpit rock\" width=\"304\" height=\"228\" /></body></html>";

Comment: please suggest another way to handle it,this code is not working 4 me, or please say what to do to  correct my present code.Thanks in advance

Comment: @Gaurav Gupta You do not need that file:///android_assets/ prefix in img src. Just set src="pulpit.jpg"

Comment: I've already told you what to do to fix your code.  I'm not going to spoonfeed you, especially given you don't appear to participate in the SO community.